# Unity game lags on Android devices after enabling 64bit

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

Our gameplay runs 60fps on most modern Android devices, but when we enable 64bit (in order to meet Google Play's new requirement) the gameplay starts to lag and freeze periodically.

---

Runs 60fps smoothly on these settings:

### [image]

Lags and freezes on these settings:
[image]

---

The issue is most apparent on Huawei P20 lite (it had run at 60fps before enabling 64bit).

Does anyone have an idea of what might be the issue?

Comment: I would suggest you to check plugins that you installed in unity (if any). Maybe one of your plugins does not fully support 64-bit. Worth to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed all of the Debug.Log() calls that are executed during gameplay and it fixed the issue.

I probably shouldn't have had them in there anyway, but out of curiosity... does anyone know why these would be a problem for 64bit when it was not an issue in 32bit?